# ASP.NET MVC 4 having one Domain Model for multiple applications and caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I am converting ASP.Net Web Forms applications to MVC 4. These applications display common items and could use one domain model for most of the items that need to be displayed. The applications only display data and do not modify the data.

Currently, when a user visits a page, the data is retrieved from an Oracle database. The page is updated with Update Panels every 30 seconds. So, if several users leave their pages open (which is common), each one will hit the database approx. every 30 seconds.

The database data is updated every 3 minutes.

What I would like to do is have the domain model updated every 30 seconds and the applications get the data from the model. So, every time a page request is made, the data is gotten from the model. Since all of the application's data are retrieved from the same domain model, they will all be the same. This should also reduce the amount of times the database is hit and hopefully speed up page reloading (and Ajax calls).

So,
- If it is the first time the domain model is being used, populate it from the database.
- If it has been less than or equal to 30 seconds, applications use the domain model
- If it has been more than 30 seconds, the model repopulates from the database and applications gets the data from the model.

Is it possible to have these multiple applications use one domain model? And, if it is possible to cache the domain model somehow, how can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache the result of the database call in your controller.

```
public ActionResult MyController()
{
    var cache = HttpContext.Cache;
    var model = cache["key"];
    if (model == null) {
        model = GetData();
        cache.Insert(
           "key", 
           model, 
           null, 
           DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30), 
           System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Or you cache the entire view by adding an [OutputCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) attribute to your controller.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult MyController()
{        
    var model = GetData();
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate that `UpdatePanel` functionality in jQuery AJAX by using a timeout to poll the server, whilst also sending your Model to the server.

Basically, your page loads, your `HttpGet` action method would populate your model from the database and then send it to your view.

Firstly, you'd have to have a Partial view that'd act as your `UpdatePanel`, wrapped in a container we can reference in jQuery:

```
<div id="stateContainer">
    @Html.Partial("YourPartial", Model)
</div>
```

Your jQuery would then do something like:

```
setInterval("pollServer()", 30000);

function pollServer() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("PollForUpdate")',
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            $("#stateContainer").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Then your action method `PollForUpdate` would look something like:

```
public ActionResult PollForUpdate(YourModel Model)
{
    ModelState.Clear();

    //fill your Model object with your database stuff

    return View("YourPartial", Model);
}
```

Comment: I liked both solutions but I had to vote for the one I implemented. Thanks